# Light on every model and not in the whole scene

Tags: xna, models, lighting

I am using a custom shader and try to pass the effect on my `Models` like that:

```
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Model.Meshes)
{
       foreach (ModelMeshPart part in mesh.MeshParts)
       {
           part.Effect = effect;
       }
       mesh.Draw();
}
```

My only issue is that every `Model` now has its own light source in it. Why is this happening and is this a problem of my shader?

---

Edit:

These are the parameters passed to the shader:

```
      private void Get_lambertEffect()
            {
                if (_lambertEffect == null) _lambertEffect = Engine.LambertEffect;

                //Lambert technique (LambertWithShadows, LambertWithShadows2x2PCF, LambertWithShadows3x3PCF)
                _lambertEffect.CurrentTechnique = _lambertEffect.Techniques["LambertWithShadows3x3PCF"];
                _lambertEffect.Parameters["texelSize"].SetValue(Engine.ShadowMap.TexelSize);

                //ShadowMap parameters
                _lambertEffect.Parameters["lightViewProjection"].SetValue(Engine.ShadowMap.LightViewProjectionMatrix);
                _lambertEffect.Parameters["textureScaleBias"].SetValue(Engine.ShadowMap.TextureScaleBiasMatrix);
                _lambertEffect.Parameters["depthBias"].SetValue(Engine.ShadowMap.DepthBias);
                _lambertEffect.Parameters["shadowMap"].SetValue(Engine.ShadowMap.ShadowMapTexture);

                //Camera view and projection parameters
                _lambertEffect.Parameters["view"].SetValue(Engine._camera.ViewMatrix);
                _lambertEffect.Parameters["projection"].SetValue(Engine._camera.ProjectionMatrix);
                _lambertEffect.Parameters["world"].SetValue(
                Matrix.CreateScale(Size) *
                world
            );
                //Light and color
                _lambertEffect.Parameters["lightDir"].SetValue(Engine._sourceLight.Direction);
                _lambertEffect.Parameters["lightColor"].SetValue(Engine._sourceLight.Color);
                _lambertEffect.Parameters["materialAmbient"].SetValue(Engine.Material.Ambient);
                _lambertEffect.Parameters["materialDiffuse"].SetValue(Engine.Material.Diffuse);
                _lambertEffect.Parameters["colorMap"].SetValue(ColorTexture.Create(Engine.GraphicsDevice, Color.Red));

            }
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: By "own light source" do you mean, that each model is illuminated by a different light source and you only want one light source in the scene? Need to see your shader...

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. The shader was working fine when I was working with primitives but now that I switched to Models I am having this issue. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: maybe we could have a look at the parameters passed to the shader

Comment: Just uploaded them

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what this looks like? I can't figure out what you mean by "each model has its own light source"

Comment: Done, image is uploaded

Comment: You are passing a "LightDir" to the shader - yet the screenshot looks like you are rendering a point light. For correct per pixel lighting with a point light you'll need to pass the light's world position into the shader, and calculate the lightDir for every pixel in the shader..

Comment: I'm doing that.

Comment: I had to use  `Matrix.Transpose(Matrix.Invert(world))` and then multiply it with my normals in the shader. That did the trick.